# Iterating over mutable lists

Tags: python, mutable

This was an example code of potential errors that could occur while working with mutable lists (from an exercise).

```
my_list = [1,2,5,4]
for i in my_list:
    print(i)
    my_list.remove(i)
print(my_list)
```

It prints

```
1
5
[2, 4]
```

But why does it react like it does?

Comment: It is not recommended to operate the list when you iterate it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strange result when removing item from a list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260097/1431750)